# Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS takes forever to boot

Tags: 18.04

I have done a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS. Please note this is my first Ubuntu install ever! Sometimes it boots normally but sometimes it doesn't boot at all. It keeps showing the Ubuntu load screen. At this moment when I press any keys the screen starts to flicker. When this happens I restart the laptop and keep doing this until it successfully boots and shows the login screen. When I see the logs, it shows the following entries:

```
10:40:37 PM gdm3: GLib: g_hash_table_find: assertion 'version == hash_table->version' failed
10:35:33 PM gnome-session-b: Unrecoverable failure in required component org.gnome.Shell.desktop
10:31:59 PM gdm-session-wor: pam_systemd(gdm-launch-environment:session): Failed to create session: Start job for unit user@121.service failed with 'failed'
10:31:59 PM systemd: Failed to start User Manager for UID 121.
10:31:59 PM gdm-session-wor: pam_systemd(gdm-launch-environment:session): Failed to create session: Start job for unit user@121.service failed with 'failed'
10:31:59 PM systemd: Failed to start User Manager for UID 121.
10:31:58 PM gdm-session-wor: pam_systemd(gdm-launch-environment:session): Failed to create session: Start job for unit user@121.service failed with 'failed'
10:31:58 PM systemd: Failed to start User Manager for UID 121.
10:31:58 PM gdm-session-wor: pam_systemd(gdm-launch-environment:session): Failed to create session: Start job for unit user@121.service failed with 'failed'
10:31:58 PM systemd: Failed to start User Manager for UID 121.
10:31:58 PM gdm-session-wor: pam_systemd(gdm-launch-environment:session): Failed to create session: Start job for unit user@121.service failed with 'failed'
10:31:58 PM systemd: Failed to start User Manager for UID 121.
10:31:58 PM gdm-session-wor: pam_systemd(gdm-launch-environment:session): Failed to create session: Start job for unit user@121.service failed with 'failed'
10:31:58 PM systemd: Failed to start User Manager for UID 121.
10:31:58 PM gdm-session-wor: pam_systemd(gdm-launch-environment:session): Failed to create session: Start job for unit user@121.service failed with 'failed'
```

I have no idea how to resolve this issue. Please help! Please find my machine details below.

1. Processor: Intel® Core™ i5-2410M CPU @ 2.30GHz × 4
2. Graphics: Intel® Sandybridge Mobile
3. GNOME: 3.28.2
4. OS Type: 64-bit

Comment: This may be a long shot but try this command: `cat /etc/environment`, then edit your question above and add the output of the command to it. `PAM` has been known to break on a faulty environment file.

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 1):

You may have a problem with an older computer, with an older GPU. Try this...

`sudo -H gedit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf` # edit this file

change:

#WaylandEnable=false

to:

WaylandEnable=false

Save the file and quit `gedit`. Then reboot.

Comment: Do you mean to set WaylandEnable=true or to un-comment it?

Comment: @MuhammadAnasKhan No. "false" is correct.

Comment: Okay let me try to un-comment it

Comment: @MuhammadAnasKhan Does it work?

Comment: I have been monitoring the boot since a week now. Its not happening again. May be because I did apply the updates...